# Will a multi-coulmn Index (name,type) be useful for where clause with in operator

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-indexes

I have a table where i have a multi column index (name, type). Will the index be helpful for a query like

```
Select *
from [table_name] a
where a.name = '[some_name]' and a.type in ('1','2','3')
```

or would be better to have a query like,

```
Select *
from [table_name] a
where a.name = '[some_name]' and (a.type = '1' or a.type = '2' or a.type = '3')
```

Let's say the table has millions of records

Comment: You can answer this question yourself by using [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to analyze the index usage of queries.

Answer (score 0):

The index will be helpful, most likely.  I say most likely  because it depends on the nature of the `name` column.  If there are millions of rows but only a few different possible values for `Name` (a condition of low [selectivity](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq167/)) then the index might not be so helpful, but that doesn't seem likely.

And it doesn't matter if you use `IN` or `=` and `OR`, the query plan should end up being the same.

Answer (score 0):

A big factor is SELECT * . If your WHERE clause will pull back 80% of the table then it might be quicker for the query to SCAN the entire table rather than use the index to perform a LOOKUP, because the Table will be needed to fulfil the *.

If you only SELECT a limited number of Columns and all of those column exist inside the Index then only the Index will need to be read and not the table.